# R: take one record per 30 days within each group

Tags: r, group-by, diff, days

I have a dataset with over 1000 unique IDs and for each ID about 15 Surgery Codes done on different Dates(recorded as Days Diff)

I want to take only 1 record per 30 days within the group of each surgery code for each ID.

Adding a demo data here:

```
   ID Age Diag.Date Surgery.Code Days.diff
1   1  67  4/8/2011         A364       421
2   1  67  4/8/2011         A364      1197
3   1  67  4/8/2011         A364      2207
4   1  67  4/8/2011         A364      2226
5   1  67  4/8/2011         A364      2247
6   1  67  4/8/2011         A364      2254
7   1  67  4/8/2011         A364      2331
8   1  67  4/8/2011         A364      2367
9   1  67  4/8/2011         A364      2905
10  1  67  4/8/2011         A364      2918
11  1  67  4/8/2011         D365      2200
12  1  67  4/8/2011         D441       308
13  1  67  4/8/2011         D443       218
14  1  67  4/8/2011         A446       308
15  2  56  6/4/2018         A453      2260
16  2  56  6/4/2018         D453       645
17  2  56  6/4/2018         D453      3095
18  2  56  6/4/2018         B453       645
```

Diff of 2226-2207 days is 19 days so row4 will delete, again diff of 2247-2207 days is 40 days so row5 will get recorded.
Again diff of 2254-2247 days is 7 days so row6 will get deleted.
Similarly, row10 will get deleted.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please do not (only) post an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use `dplyr::group_by(ID, Surgery.Code)` to filter within individuals and surgeries;
2. Within each group, use `Days.diff - dplyr::lag(Days.diff) <= 30` to test for adjacent rows within 30 days;
3. Because the results of (2) may change when rows are removed, you'll want to iterate by removing one row at a time per group, then re-testing. You can use `while` to iterate until no more cases are detected.

```r
library(dplyr)

filtered <- surgeries %>% 
  group_by(ID, Surgery.Code) %>% 
  mutate(within30 = if_else(
    Days.diff - lag(Days.diff) <= 30, 
    row_number(), 
    NA_integer_
  ))

while (any(!is.na(filtered$within30))) {
  filtered <- filtered %>% 
    mutate(within30 = if_else(
      Days.diff - lag(Days.diff) <= 30, 
      row_number(), 
      NA_integer_
    )) %>% 
    filter(is.na(within30) | within30 != min(within30, na.rm = TRUE))
}

filtered %>% 
  select(!within30) %>% 
  ungroup()

#> # A tibble: 15 x 5
#>       ID   Age Diag.Date Surgery.Code Days.diff
#>    <int> <int> <chr>     <chr>            <int>
#>  1     1    67 4/8/2011  A364               421
#>  2     1    67 4/8/2011  A364              1197
#>  3     1    67 4/8/2011  A364              2207
#>  4     1    67 4/8/2011  A364              2247
#>  5     1    67 4/8/2011  A364              2331
#>  6     1    67 4/8/2011  A364              2367
#>  7     1    67 4/8/2011  A364              2905
#>  8     1    67 4/8/2011  D365              2200
#>  9     1    67 4/8/2011  D441               308
#> 10     1    67 4/8/2011  D443               218
#> 11     1    67 4/8/2011  A446               308
#> 12     2    56 6/4/2018  A453              2260
#> 13     2    56 6/4/2018  D453               645
#> 14     2    56 6/4/2018  D453              3095
#> 15     2    56 6/4/2018  B453               645
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: This code works great! But is there any other function that can be used here instead of while loop? My original data is huge and this code has been now running for more than 10 hours now!

Comment: @TriparnaPoddar Yikes! You could try implementing it in [{Rcpp}](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp); see also the [chapter on re-implementing R functions in C](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/rcpp.html) from *Advanced R.*